# Gulp task output missing file

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass, gulp-concat

**I cant create output.css file in root directory via gulp ..** I want output compressed one file with stylesheet, but the gulp doesnt work them.

```
I have this structure

     - bower_components

         - bootstrap

           - sass

             - custom.scss

     - output.css
```

**my gulp file:**

```
var gulp             = require('gulp'),
    sass             = require('gulp-sass'),
    watch            = require('gulp-watch');
var concat           = require('gulp-concat');


gulp.task('scss', function () {
    return gulp.src('bower_components/bootstrap/scss/_custom.scss')
        .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}))
        .pipe(concat('output.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {

    gulp.watch('bower_components/bootstrap/scss/_custom.scss', ['scss']);

});

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

Comment: I see your file structure uses the directory "sass" but your gulpfile uses "scss".

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include the 'scss' task in your default task.

`gulp.task('default', ['scss', 'watch']);`